# Indent paragraph within enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, enumitem

I am using the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en) package to create an `enumerate` environment labeled by letters (a), (b).

I would like to indent the "Lorem ipsum" text further in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item{apples\\{\small Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}}
  \item{bananas\\{\small Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}}
\end{enumerate}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

which gives this output:

[image: mwe]

I would like the paragraphs indented within the `enumerate` environment like this (shown using a word processor):

[image: desired]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `desc`ription as an `\item` of a separate list (`itemize`) that doesn't have any label. Or, wrap it inside something like `\itemdesc`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\itemdesc}[2][]{%
  \begin{itemize}[nosep,#1]
    \item[]\small#2
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item apples
  \itemdesc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
  
  \item bananas
  \itemdesc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
\end{enumerate}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```